# Simple Injector pass hard coded values into constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

In [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) I can do the following:

```
container.RegisterSingle<IAuctionContext>(() => new AuctionContext(
    new Uri("http://localhost:60001/AuctionDataService.svc/")));
```

What I am doing here is saying that when `IAuctionContext` is found, replace it with this new `AuctionContext`. The problem is that with the call to `RegisterSingle`, only a single instance of `AuctionContext` will be used.  What I'd like it to be able to pass in a `Uri` parameter as above but not have the single instance but allow a new instance each time.

How is this possible?

Comment: I've edited your question and removed your signature per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts. Please refrain from using signatures. =)

Comment: I will keep this in mind for next time, thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The value you are trying to inject is a simple hard-coded value. For constant values like hard-coded values and configuration values, just use the `Register` method:

```cs
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:60001/AuctionDataService.svc/");

container.Register<IAuctionContext>(() => new AuctionContext(uri));
```

The `Register` method ensures a new instance is returned each time.

When it comes to injecting values that could change during the course of the application, please read [this article about injecting runtime data](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).